# SSR head.querySelector is not a function

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

On Angular/ionic running into this error on ssr build `head.querySelector is not a function`. When examining the cause of it, it shows it is coming from `bootstrapLazy`. I've looked for what this `bootstrapLazy` is but can't seem to find where this is from.
Search on the internet shows up as stencil in ionic; I'm not using stencil and I'm not sure if it's due to lazy loading but I do not seem to see it.

Does anyone know what this is? Or how I can get rid of it on ssr build?

```
const bootstrapLazy = (lazyBundles, options = {}) => {
    const endBootstrap = createTime();
    const cmpTags = [];
    const exclude = options.exclude || [];
    const customElements = win.customElements;
    const head = doc.head;
    const metaCharset = /*@__PURE__*/ head.querySelector('meta[charset]'); // triggered here.
    const visibilityStyle = /*@__PURE__*/ doc.createElement('style');
    const deferredConnectedCallbacks = [];
    const styles = /*@__PURE__*/ doc.querySelectorAll(`[${HYDRATED_STYLE_ID}]`);
    let appLoadFallback;
    let isBootstrapping = true;
```

Comment: Have you already tried `constructot(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document:any) { }` and `(<Document>this.document).querySelectorAll('head meta[charset]')`?

Comment: @Pieterjan where would that go? I tried it in app component. Didn't work. I just noticed this is coming from ionic core.

Comment: Sorry I only have experience with Angular. I know for a fact that in angular it's best to avoid the DOM `document` especially when using SSR, and inject the provider instead. I wouldn't do DOM manipulations in `bootstrapModule`. But in the `AppComponent` it should work. What's the error you get?

Comment: @Pieterjan yeah im aware of DOM issues, especially in SSR since it is sever side. The error is the same when I added the document injection. It didn't get rid of `head.querySelector`.

Comment: did you fix this issue?

Comment: @SvetoslavAtanasov unfortunately no, the ssr created a lot of issues

Comment: Any updates facing same issue.

Comment: @Nicks unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 0):

It seem you missed to install `@ionic/angular-server` and import in `app.server.module.ts`, insure that your `app.server.module.ts` looks like

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerModule } from '@angular/platform-server';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { IonicServerModule } from '@ionic/angular-server';

@NgModule({
  imports: [AppModule, ServerModule, IonicServerModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppServerModule {}
```

Also insure that your `@ionic/angular-server` matches the version `@ionic/angular`.

Comment: This did not solve for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I use domino to shimming the window and document object for ssr.

My solution is to remove the domino and all the window and document shimming from server.ts. Then I used isPlatformBrowser()/isPlatformServer() functions from Angular, everywhere I use window and document in my App.

Example (pseudo code)

```
constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: string) {}

somefunction() {
 if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
  document.localStorage....
 }
}
```

In this case the document part is only executed in the browser and not at the server. This fixed the issue for me.